# Prevent LDAP requests

Tags: windows, kerberos, srv-record

I have a work laptop that I connect to my local lan as well. On it I have a pi-hole. On it I can see that the laptop makes an awful lot of requests to the office domain which of course is not available at home. I am playing around with it and want to see if I can prevent these calls being made. I realize that these should be enabled at the office but want to understand how to stop them nonetheless.

The requests are multiple, but the high number of calls go to:
_ldap._tcp.zuckhq._sites.dc._msdcs.zuck.global
_ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.zuck.global
_ldap._tcp.bf704556-2e90.domains._msdcs.zuck.global
_kerberos._tcp.dc._msdcs.zuck.global
_kerberos._tcp.zuckhq._sites.dc._msdcs.zuck.global

These are all SRV requests so I cannot stop them in the hosts file but what I have read is that I have to stop them in the lmhosts file. Unfortunately I have no experience with that file. I have read lots of stuff but just can't figure it out so I decided I should just ask.

To be concrete, what I want is to stop these SRV calls to go out of the laptop so I want them directed to 0.0.0.0 like I have managed to do with simple A and PTR calls (in the hosts file)

Comment: Why/How is this a problem?

Comment: The problem is that there are some many requests send to my pi-hole that I can no longer read the logs. I know that that is a pi-hole problem but it brought to my attention that there are many "office" calls on my home network and I just want to know how to block these